# How to store cookie set in mid-redirection through Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

Let's say I log in at a.com/login
While waiting for the login request to be processed, I'm redirected to b.com, where a few cookies are set.
Miliseconds later, I am again redirected, this time, to a.com/logged_in_user.

I try to execute `driver.get_cookies()`, but it's too late. I can only retrieve cookies for domain a.com.

Is there a way to stop execution at b.com, store cookies, and then allow redirection to proceed? How can this be done?

Comment: You probably need to get them directly from the headers... or go to b.com to get them.  You can also view them in your browser (manually) Why are you trying to store those cookies?

Comment: i need to store cookies from different domains on a redis session so i can automate different procedures without logging in to the same two websites over and over. One of them is solved, the other uses oauth/auth0, which is the case.

Comment: might consider using a profile that's already logged in.  You can set the driver to use a specific profile.  These cookies will most likely be session-based anyway... so all you want is the "remember me" types.